# Converting string to date gives wrong date (+1)

Tags: angular, typescript, casting

I have seen few posts in stack overflow regarding dates and timezone issue but didn't get any idea.
I have date column in table and I have it as string so before saving to db , I am converting those column as date and sending to server.

TS:

```
item.effectiveDate=new Date(item.effectiveDate);
```

In **Console.log(item.effectiveDate)**, am getting correct date lets say i gave **9th sep 2020**

Console Log:

```
 effectiveDate: Wed Sep 09 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

But to server side dates are sent like 1 day lesser:

In DB:

```
EffectiveDate
2020-09-08 18:30:00.000
```

What i expect is ,**2020-09-09 00:00:00.000**

Comment: Your date in DB is in GMT/UTC format/zone and in console you are getting it in IST.

Comment: Any idea on how to acheive this? I tried converting with possible ways.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in handling dates but parsing the date in UTC format solved the issue for me.

Change your TS code as below:

```
item.effectiveDate=new Date(Date.parse(item.effectiveDate+"T00:00:00+0000"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually databases will have UTC dates but you can handle conversion at UI level based on users timezone. You can utilize either https://date-fns.org/ or https://momentjs.com/ to handle conversions at UI level.

I would suggest to use standard ISO format to transfer datetime from backend to frontend to preserve timezone information.
Ex. `2020-08-14T10:41:20+05:30`

Comment: Thank you for your answer !